# Compiling library in linux when in another folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation

I'm new in Linux. I have a library in a folder next to my C program source but I don't know how to compile it. I've compiled everything when my library was in the same folder as program code file. However, I do not understand how to use the library from another location?

Comment: Could you be more specific, such as give some examples?

Comment: Are you using a build system (like Autotools) or just a compiler?

Comment: Which library are you taking about? How did you compile it? Why do you need to build it in another *directory* (not folder)?

Comment: You could use [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS)

Answer (score 3):

Use gcc's `-L` option to specify where your library located, and `-l` option to specify what your library is.
If you're using '`make`' to build your program, just open the Makefile and find out where -L option has used.

For example,

```
gcc -L ./my_program/my_library -lmylib -o my_executable ./my_program/src/my_program.c
```

Also, you can use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to specify your library path to your program.

Say that you have ready to run your excutable, but the library is not in any standard library path (such as /usr/lib),
then you can run your program by following command.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/my_name/my_program/my_library my_executable
```